# How to create 3-column flexbox container with 1 column always center?

Tags: css, flexbox

I create something like this:

[image]

**The challenge is to center blue column horizontally regardless of the content in the side columns.**

Now it turns out like this:

[image]

But I want it to be this way:

[image]

**How to do it?**

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}

.center-box {
  flex-basis: 70px;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.side-box {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="side-box left">text</div>
    <div class="center-box">center</div>
    <div class="side-box right">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="side-box left">long text</div>
    <div class="center-box">center</div>
    <div class="side-box right">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="side-box left">text</div>
    <div class="center-box">center</div>
    <div class="side-box right">long text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you supply us some code what you are doing? Css and HTML please.

Comment: @Dorvalla Yes, added the question.

Comment: Just add flex: 1 0 33%; to each column/box